# Jenkins dynamic passing of a variable to a parameter

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to pass a variable to the parameter.
I have a structure of pipeline: JOB_NAME > env (ex. test, dev as multibranch pipeline type) > branches

I want to display different parameters (in GUI) for the user depending on the name of the env.
In Jenkinsfile I created a simple function. Variable envName has a type of env (test, dev, etc.) and it's ok.

```
def getEnvName() {
    envName = "${JOB_NAME.split('/')[1]}"
}
```

I tried to use the plugin Active Choices (https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) but I cannot pass envName to the parameter.

Part of the implementation of the plugin in code.

```
properties([
parameters([
    [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
        name: 'Env', 
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    'return[\'Could not get Env\']'
            ], 
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: '''
                    HERE I NEED MY envName VARIABLE
                    '''
            ]
        ]
    ], 
    [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
        name: 'Server', 
        referencedParameters: 'Env', 
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
            ], 
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    ''' if (Env.equals("test")){
                            return["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test5"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("dev")){
                            return["dev1","dev2","dev3"]
                        }
                    '''
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
])
```

Has anyone tried to do something like this?
I'm open to any solution. Thanks!