# How to get access to values from input tag rendered by DynamicReferenceParameter in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is my code, here choice2 is dependent on choice.
How can I get the value of input tag(value comes from user) in the pipleine.

```
properties([
    parameters([
        
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_RADIO', 
            description: 'Select a choice', 
            filterLength: 1, 
            filterable: false, 
            name: 'choice1', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-7601235200970', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 'return[\'aaa\',\'bbb\']'
                ]
            ]
        ], 
        
        [
            $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
            name: 'choice2', 
            referencedParameters: 'choice1', 
            description: 'Active Choices Reactive parameter', 
            omitValueField: true,
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-7601237141171', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 'return ["error"]'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 'if(choice1.equals("aaa")){return "<input name=\'Aws\' value=\'\' class=\'setting-input\' type=\'text\'>"} else {return "Not Required"}'
                ]
            ]
        ]
        
        
    ])
])


pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Print the Values') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo "${params.choice2}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the value that user enters.
I'm getting null as it's value.
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the parameter should be displayed based on what the user provides.

Here is my thread with the same problem: [Jenkins dynamic passing of a variable to a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857980/jenkins-dynamic-passing-of-a-variable-to-a-parameter)

Honestly, I spent many hours trying to solve this but I failed.